# LAN not working after installing OpenVPN

Tags: 14.04, openvpn

I installed openvpn in Ubuntu 16.04 and LAN stopped working though it shows connected in settings and in Desktop bar.

It's still happening after removing openvpn and its dependencies too.

Comment: have you restarted your computer

Comment: Yeah but I found the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved

I just wents to **Settings > wired connection** then selected **ipv4** and set **dhcp address** to **automatic**, and rebooted.